# karma custom launcher: Want to run bash script containing curl command, what must it return?

Tags: javascript, bash, shell, testing, karma-runner

For running my  javascript tests, I have written a one-line Bash script that triggers a CI build in Teamcity via curl.

I want it to run automatically after changing one of the javascript test files.
I have set up the Karma Testrunner to watch the file system. That works.

Now I want to run my bash script  once but I don't know what it should return so that karma knows that it was launched successfully.

```
karma start --browsers ~/bin/tcbuild.sh
```

Result

```
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.10.9 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser /home/knb/bin/tcbuild.sh
ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start /home/knb/bin/tcbuild.sh

INFO [launcher]: Trying to start /home/knb/bin/tcbuild.sh again.
ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start /home/knb/bin/tcbuild.sh

INFO [launcher]: Trying to start /home/knb/bin/tcbuild.sh again.
```

But the script has actually started (and triggered 3 builds within a couple of seconds), but karma does not realize this.

I want karma to try to start the shell script only once. 
What must the script return to karma?

Do I have to "daemonize" the shell script?

The script `~/bin/tcbuild.sh` looks like this, as I said, it is a one-liner:

```
#!/bin/bash

curl --user myacc:secrit --anyauth --url "http://my.ciserver.com:8111/app/rest/buildQueue" --request POST --header "Content-Type:application/xml" --data-binary @/opt/teamcity/build-js-qunit.xml
```

**Update:**

My machine is called wb3. Chrome instance launched by Karma listens on port 9877.

```
lsof -u knb -i | grep 9877
```

yields

```
    COMMAND     PID USER   FD      TYPE             DEVICE   SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
    node      57786  knb   12u     IPv4            8271405        0t0      TCP *:9877 (LISTEN)
    node      57786  knb   14u     IPv4            8272554        0t0      TCP wb3:9877->wb3:33503 (ESTABLISHED)
    node      57786  knb   19u     IPv4            8274193        0t0      TCP    
wb3:9877->wb3:33507 (ESTABLISHED)
    node      57786  knb   22u     IPv4            8274196        0t0      TCP wb3:9877->wb3:33511 (ESTABLISHED)
    chrome    57978  knb   80u     IPv4            8270580        0t0      TCP wb3:33503->wb3:9877 (ESTABLISHED)
    chrome    57978  knb   81u     IPv4            8270583        0t0      TCP wb3:33504->wb3:9877 (ESTABLISHED
```

Seems I need to keep the curl command alive and communicating with node.

Comment: Well, likely it exits with non-zero status. Try to add something like `RC=$?; echo "rc=$RC at $(date)" >> /var/tmp/tcbuild.log; exit $RC` after the curl invocation.

Comment: Thanks  @user3159253, I tried your snippet, and I've independently, previously tried `exit 0` after the curl command, but that does not change karma's behaviour. I suspect I must keep the process alive and/or a socket open, or  something.

Comment: [Here](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/config/browsers.html) is mentioned that the browser script should take one argument, an URL with id, which should be passed to the server for proper identification of the browser.

Comment: @user3159253 But in the line right before that sentence, in the code example it says `karma start --browsers /usr/local/bin/custom-browser.sh`. This is contradictory. No URL with id param given.

Comment: This line only says that karma is run with 3 arguments, 'start', '--browsers', and the path to the custom browser command. In fact it says nothing about how this custom browser command will be invoked.

Comment: So, I guess, that the script receives the URL argument (check `$@`) upon the invocation, and you simply ignore that argument.

Comment: @user3159253 Another guy had similar issue, got answer by karma's creator:  https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/796#issuecomment-27611103